# How to access Windows PC folder on my Android Tablets without internet connection

Tags: wireless-networking, android, localhost, wireless-bridge

I am trying to access a Windows PC folder on my Android Tablets (let's say 10 Tablets). I have a video folder in my PC and I want to give access to my App to access that folder and play video. Things I have tried are:

- **Using JCIFS library and samba server but the drawback is it requires internet connection.**
- **Using WAMP Server and local host this solution was perfect until I tested it on multiple devices. It takes a lot of time to buffer big video files and sometimes fails to access videos.**

Is there any other method to do that?
Is there any other method to connect my Android tablets to Windows PC and access the video files from a folder?

Comment: You mean access with the PC and the tablet in the same network (like, connected to the same router)?

Comment: yes that's what I mean @TomYan

Comment: Are you having problem on the host side (PC) or the client side (tablet)? Since it should be easy to set up an FTP server with for example, FileZilla FTP Server, or make the folder as an SMB share with the Windows builtin feature. And you should be able to access them with one of those android file managers that supports FTP and SMB. Most importantly, I do NOT see how any of these requires Internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

### Filemanager with SMB-support

I use the Filemanager from CheetahMobile to access shares.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Cheetah+Mobile

However depending on your Windows version this can be very annoying to configure.

### FTP-Server

The quickest and most stable variant could be to set up a FTP-server

https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=server

(Where you have many good working android clients)